# how to get id from just an inserted data

Tags: php, sql

Hi guys im having difficulty on creating a logic on how to get an ID to an inserted data.My page has no userID or any. Just insertion of the data. I have two tables:

request to purchase table and ordered_items table. I separated the tables because i just need to store multiple data for items which hold an array of data.

heres my code:

```
<td><textarea name="item[]" value=""></textarea></td>
<td><textarea name="description[]" value=""></textarea></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qty[]" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" /></td>
<td><button class="add">Add</button></td>
```

and my methods are here:

```
public function insertRecord($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `request_to_purchase` (`requestedby`, `date`, `jobtitle`, `supervisor`, `notes`) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ?, ?)');

    $query->bindValue(1, $param1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(2, $param2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(3, $param3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindValue(4, $param4, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    try {

        $query->execute();

        $row = $query->rowCount();

        echo $row;

        if(count($row) > 0) {

            return true;
        } else {                
            return false;
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        die($e->getMessage());

    }

}

public function insertItem($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5, $arg6) {

    $query = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `ordered_item` (`rtp_id`, `item`, `description`, `qty`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    $query->bindValue(1, $arg1);
    $query->bindValue(2, $arg2);
    $query->bindValue(3, $arg3);
    $query->bindValue(4, $arg4);
    $query->bindValue(5, $arg5);
    $query->bindValue(6, $arg6);
}
```

How do i get the rtp_id from request_to_purchase table so that i can insert it on the ordered item table. By then I can make a query `Select * from ordered item table where rtp_id = ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PDO you can do like this:

```
$db->lastInsertId('yourIdColumn');
```

Docs Link: http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

In your code snippet.

```
  if(count($row) > 0) {

        return $this->$db->lastInsertId();
    } else {                
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: i got this error = Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()

Comment: what code you have used. because lastInsertId is method of PDO class. how are you using it? Can you show the code

Answer (score 1):

Look at here [Last Insert Id](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://php.net/mysql_insert_id&ei=3payUsPWEsK3rged_4Bg&usg=AFQjCNHM0TSfonU0ScKxuUmpfooFVDcJFQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.bmk) Already function available in PHP.

In your problem Use

```
$query->execute();
$last_inserted_id = $query->insert_id;
```

Comment: i got this error = Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$db->lastInsertId();
```

For more info. see [DOC](http://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

`lastInsertId` is a method of `PDO`, not `PDOStatement`

Comment: i got this error = Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()